# Calabash Android: Cannot query subclass of WebView

Tags: android, webview, subclass, calabash

I am currently attempting to use calabash-android to query the HTML content of a webview.

This webview is a custom subclass of android.webkit.WebView.

When I perform `query ("webView")` using the calabash-android I receive no results.
When I  perform `query ("MyCustomWebView")` the custom webview is returned, however, trying to perform a query such as `query('MyCustomWebView css: "*"')` the app crashes and the console sees connection refused.

Calabash-android Version: 0.5.8
Tested on Android Emulators: Nexus 5 5.0, Nexus 5 5.1 (All architectures)

Comment: Does <query "*"> give you anything?

Comment: `query('*')` gives me all elements on the page, returning my CustomWebView with class CustomWebView. Also `query ("CustomWebView"), :getClass, :getSuperclass` returns `android.webkit.WebView`

Comment: You have not supplied enough information. What version of Calabash-Android are you using? What is the result of `query('MyCustomWebView css: "*"')`? What is the class of MyCustomWebView? (does it inherit from android.widget.WebView) Which device are you testing on? (in particular the OS) Does adb logcat contain any interesting information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in calabash-android 0.5.12